# How to show Clear Shopping Cart in magento 2

Tags: css, shopping-cart, magento2.2.6

I wish to show Clear Shopping cart button in cart page.

In default magento it was `display:none`, So need to show only Clear Shopping
 cart button as mentioned like below image.

Where I need to override this CSS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did this by below css

```
.checkout-cart-index .form-cart .cart .action.clear {
    display: block;
}
```

You can put this css in any css file. That will override existing css.

Comment: It but it was showing a clear shopping cart button in smaller size, the text on the button is not dispalying

Comment: @Jaisa Its depend on your css. You need to add custom css for this button as per your requirements. Do inspect element and check css